# Will Stripe API retry a Webhook request if my server was unable to receive it?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, webhooks

If I set up a Stripe Webhook to send a request to `http://my.website.io` but, for whatever reason, my server is down at the time or somehow unable to process the request, will Stripe retry the request? Or do I need to be responsible for polling them to ensure my copy of the data is up-to-date?

I couldn't find anything in Stripe's docs about retrying a Webhook request (and I can understand why they wouldn't), but I just want to make sure I didn't miss it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes. Webhooks are retried once an hour for up to 3 days or until a 200 status code is returned.

See: https://stripe.com/blog/webhooks

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: Perhaps this was true at the time, but Stripe webhooks are no longer tried once per hour. Currently they use "exponential backoff" over three days, with no further details. Personally I see a retries after 1 minute, 1 hour, 4 hours, then 14 hours.